# ORA-04091: table xx_xx is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

So i have to create a trigger which will log changes made to a table called 'passengerlist1' into an extra table called 'logs'.

The logs table:

```
create table logs (
  p_name varchar(255),
  p_surname varchar(255),
  f_id number,
  time_stamp timestamp
);
```

Passengerlist1 table has the following attributes: **FLIGHTID, PERSONID, SEATNUMBER.**

There is another table involed called PERSON1 with attributes: **PERSONID, GIVENNAME, FAMILYNAME, DATEOFBIRTH.** This is the table from where i need to select the givenname and familyname of a person and store it into the 'logs' table in case changes are made to 'passengerlist1' table. From 'passengerlist1' table i only need to select the FLIGHTID and store it into the 'logs' table.

So with this out of the way here is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_changes 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON passengerlist1
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
 t_name varchar2(255);
 t_surname varchar2(255);
BEGIN
  BEGIN

   IF DELETING THEN
    SELECT PERSON1.GIVENNAME INTO T_NAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :OLD.FLIGHTID;

    SELECT PERSON1.FAMILYNAME INTO T_SURNAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :OLD.FLIGHTID;

    INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES (T_NAME, T_SURNAME, :OLD.FLIGHTID, SYSDATE);
   END IF;

   IF UPDATING THEN

    SELECT PERSON1.GIVENNAME INTO T_NAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :NEW.FLIGHTID;

     SELECT PERSON1.FAMILYNAME INTO T_SURNAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :NEW.FLIGHTID;

    INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES (T_NAME, T_SURNAME, :NEW.FLIGHTID, SYSDATE);
   END IF;

   IF INSERTING THEN
      SELECT PERSON1.GIVENNAME INTO T_NAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :NEW.FLIGHTID;

     SELECT PERSON1.FAMILYNAME INTO T_SURNAME FROM 
      PERSON1 JOIN PASSENGERLIST1 
      ON PERSON1.PERSONID = PASSENGERLIST1.PERSONID
      WHERE PASSENGERLIST1.FLIGHTID = :NEW.FLIGHTID;

      INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES (T_NAME, T_SURNAME, :NEW.FLIGHTID, SYSDATE);
   END IF;
END;
END;
/
```

Now using the following anonymous block:

```
begin
 delete from passengerlist1 where flightid = 1;
end;
/
```

to make some changes to passengerlist1 table, being that i defined this trigger as an **AFTER** trigger, i was expecting the changes to take effect first, then the trigger would fire insert into the 'logs' table. But instead i get this error:

**ORA-04091: table xx_passengerlist1 is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**

What am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't query a mutating table in the trigger.
See this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

> **Trigger Restrictions on Mutating Tables**
>
> A mutating table is a table that is being modified by an UPDATE,
>   DELETE, or INSERT statement, or a table that might be updated by the
>   effects of a DELETE CASCADE constraint.
>
> The session that issued the triggering statement cannot query or
>   modify a mutating table. This restriction prevents a trigger from
>   seeing an inconsistent set of data.
>
> This restriction applies to all triggers that use the FOR EACH ROW
>   clause. Views being modified in INSTEAD OF triggers are not considered
>   mutating.
>
> When a trigger encounters a mutating table, a runtime error occurs,
>   the effects of the trigger body and triggering statement are rolled
>   back, and control is returned to the user or application.

Try this code instead:

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER log_changes 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON passengerlist1
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
 t_name varchar2(255);
 t_surname varchar2(255);
BEGIN
   IF DELETING THEN
    SELECT PERSON1.GIVENNAME, PERSON1.FAMILYNAME INTO T_NAME,  T_SURNAME
    FROM PERSON1
    WHERE PERSON1.PERSONID = :OLD.PERSONID;

    INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES (T_NAME, T_SURNAME, :OLD.FLIGHTID, SYSDATE);
   END IF;

   IF UPDATING OR INSERTING THEN

     SELECT PERSON1.GIVENNAME,  PERSON1.FAMILYNAME  INTO T_NAME, T_SURNAME 
     FROM PERSON1 
     WHERE PERSON1.PERSONID = :NEW.PERSONID;

     INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES (T_NAME, T_SURNAME, :NEW.FLIGHTID, SYSDATE);
   END IF;
END;
/
```