# ORA-00936: missing expression (sql-oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

**I want to add 100 dollars to the old money, But tell me ORA-00936: missing expression**

```
create table sala(
    salary char(4));

insert into sala values(300);


create or replace trigger update_sal
after insert on sala
for each row
when(new.salary in not null)
begin
    update sala set salary=new.salary + 100;
end;
```

Comment: `insert into sala values('300');` Is that column a varchar or a number? Your data types are sketchy.

Comment: `in not null` ???

Comment: @TheImpaler '300' does not add

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes

Comment: this is number.

Comment: `insert into sala values(300);` errors waiting to happen when adding columns in the future always use the columns as well

Comment: @koki - `when(new.salary IS not null)`

Comment: What are the expected results as iam getting very confused when reading this SQL *"new.salary **in** not null"*  and reading the comments *"yes this is number."*

Comment: Can you write the correct code??

Comment: ORA-04091: table SQL_ZUMZCLIRSOEISHHYEPMNHCYIE.SALA is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "SQL_ZUMZCLIRSOEISHHYEPMNHCYIE.UPDATE_SAL", line 2

Comment: You want to add 100 to the `salary` of the previously existing rows and the `INSERT`ed rows on an `INSERT`? Or do you want to increase the `salary` of just the rows, that get `INSERT`ed?

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Tell your examiner/ instructor to take a look at the problem closely. Mutating error should be taken into consideration before attempting anything like this.

Comment: See this to know the reason of "mutating" error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723587/ora-04091-table-xx-xx-is-mutating-trigger-function-may-not-see-it

Comment: If `sala` is logically a number and you intend to perform arithmetic on it, why do you define it as a blank-padded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger syntax is not correct.

Try this:

```
create or replace trigger update_sal
before insert on sala
for each row
begin
  if :new.salary is not null then
      :new.salary := :new.salary + 100;
  end if;
end;
```

Key points:

- You can't update the same table that the trigger is on--this causes a *mutating table* error. The way to do this is by assigning the value directly, as shown above.
- You can't modify the `:NEW` value in an `after` trigger. You can do so in a `before` trigger though.
- The pseudo record is prefixed with a colon, as `:NEW`

After adding this trigger, here is the result:

```
insert into sala values(700);
select * from sala;

800
```